# Can I use Doctor of Physics degree diploma without marks for WES to immigrate to Canada

Tags: working-visas, immigration, canada, education

I have 3 degrees in Physics, Bachelor (2000-2004), Master (2004-2006), and Doctorate (2006-2009). Now in my University (www.ysu.am) at the time I was a student we had courses only in Bachelor and Master degree and only some general course of philosophy in the PhD years. So the academic transcripts are only available for the Bachelor and Master degrees. Now, I am going to apply for Education Credential Assessment at WES.org for Canada immigration. I am wondering is it ok to submit only my PhD diploma without academic transcripts/marks, or, maybe, it is safer to submit Master's degree with the marks, as that degree is enough for the program I am going to apply.

Comment: It should be okay, there are many other countries with PhDs that have no grades, so its not surprising to see it.